# AzureDevops Rest Api : Get who all updated the pipeline with date

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}?pipelineVersion={pipelineVersion}&api-version=7.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/%7BpipelineId%7D?pipelineVersion=%7BpipelineVersion%7D&api-version=7.0)

I was looking into the above azure devops rest api endpoint  , but I am  looking for an endpoint where we can find all the persons who updated the pipeline and also the date associated with it .

Comment: What kind of pipeline is this? YAML/classic based build pipeline or release pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

This part is not for Pipeline Rest Api. By default, you may use Auditing: [Access, export, and filter audit logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/audit/azure-devops-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).

As example, you may export logs to csv and use filters in Excel:

[image]

Additionally, you may use Rest Api to query or download Audits Logs: [Audit API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/audit/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)